# react-google-maps Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-google-maps/lib/places/SearchBox'

Tags: node-modules, create-react-app, react-google-maps

I have a create-react-app which uses [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps). What I want to do is to import SearchBox from 'react-google-maps/lib/places/SearchBox' but I'm getting the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-google-maps/lib/places/SearchBox' in 'D:\ReactApp\demo\src\components'
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps"
import SearchBox from 'react-google-maps/lib/places/SearchBox';
```

Other imports work normally. It looks like the problem occurs when I import a module from subdirectory i.e. /node_modules/react-google-maps/lib/....

Answer (score -1):

try to use this:

```
yarn add react-google-maps-loader --windows
npm install react-google-maps-loader --save
```

And

```
yarn add react-google-maps-loader --windows
npm install react-google-maps-loader --save
```